# Why several foreach loops do not work together?

Tags: php

I wrote this line to read three arrays and do some thing, but any thing does not running in these three foreaches!

```
foreach ($x_sort as $key => $x_name) {

    foreach ($y_sort as $key => $y_name){

        foreach ($z_sort as $key => $z_name){

            if ((!isset($y_name)) and (!isset($z_name)){
                echo $key . "." . $x_name . "," . "," . "<br>";

            }elseif ((isset($y_name)) and (!isset($z_name)){
                echo $key . "," . $x_name . "," . $key . ',' . $y_name . ',' . "<br>" ;
            }elseif ((!isset($y_name)) and (isset($z_name))){
                echo $key . "," . $x_name . ',' . ' ,' . $key . ',' . $z_name . "<br>" ;
            }elseif(isset($y_name)and isset($z_name))
            {
                echo $key . "," . $x_name . ',' . $key . ',' . $y_name . $key . ',' . $z_name . "<br>" ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing is `$key` overwriting

Comment: There are two [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP: the global scope and the local scope (function scope). The [blocks of statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.intro.php) do not introduce new scopes, consequently the `$key` variable used by the inner `foreach`-es overwrites the `$key` variable used by the outer `foreach`-es. Use different names for the variables that store the keys (f.e. `$x_key`, `$y_key`, `$z_key`) to avoid this situation.

Comment: If the syntax errors are corrected this still reads oddly.  I'd only expect the final elseif statement to execute.  Are you sure you want isset here?

Comment: What's the purpose of the code, why not add your arrays and explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: If 'does not running' means you are getting no output, you'll want to learn how to debug.  For a start to catch those syntax errors you can pass php your code with the l (lint) switch. `php -l /path/to/script.php`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight error in loop interpretation in your code.

For instance,

```
foreach ($x_sort as $key => $x_name) {

foreach ($y_sort as $key => $y_name){
```

Here both the for loops are unrelated. For a nested for loop to successfully iterate its elements, you must ensure that the value is being propagated from the top level loop.

So, your code will change to

```
foreach ($x_sort as $key => $x_name) {

foreach ($x_name as $key1 => $y_name){
```

Repeat the same procedure for the third loop.

Answer (score 0):

All suggested here solutions are still broken. I have fixed all your syntax errors, please look for all `()` and `{}`:

```
<?php

foreach ($x_sort as $x_key => $x_name) {
    foreach ($y_sort as $y_key => $y_name) {
        foreach ($z_sort as $z_key => $z_name) {
            if (
                (!isset($y_name)) and
                (!isset($z_name))
            ) {
                echo $x_key . "." . $x_name . "," . "," . "<br>";
            } elseif (
                (isset($y_name)) and
                (!isset($z_name))
            ) {
                echo $x_key . "," . $x_name . "," . $y_key . ',' . $y_name . ',' . "<br>" ;
            } elseif (
                (!isset($y_name)) and
                (isset($z_name))
            ) {
                echo $x_key . "," . $x_name . ',' . ' ,' . $z_key . ',' . $z_name . "<br>" ;
            } elseif (
                (isset($y_name)) and
                (isset($z_name))
            ) {
                echo $x_key . "," . $x_name . ',' . $y_key . ',' . $y_name . $z_key . ',' . $z_name . "<br>" ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax errors here - are namely that closing brackets are missing on the first two if expressions.